# Hide a specific user account from UAC dialog

Tags: windows-7, uac

I normally use Windows 7 under an account which is a member of the local `Users` group. When I need to install programs or do other priviledged operations, I have a second account, with a different password, which is a member of the `Administrators` group. This works well - whenever I install a new program, for instance, when the UAC dialog appears it displays a list of local administrator accounts. I can choose one and enter the password, and then the operation runs under that account. This list has just one item (my admin account), so I can immediately begin typing my password and hit Enter.

However, I have installed a program which installed its own service account (Cygwin SSHD) and this now appears first in the list. When the UAC dialog appears, I have to select the correct account before typing my password, which I forget/slows me down/is slightly irritating as the service account is never intended to be used for interactive logon as far as I'm concerned.

Is it possible to hide specific accounts from the UAC dialog, or adjust the group membership /login rights of this new service account so that it is hidden? (This is a standalone workstation; it is not part of a domain.)

ps. For those familiar with the Cygwin SSHD install process this is the `cyg_server` account, needed for SSHD to impersonate other users on the system when they login, from what I understand. Does this mean it does in fact need interactive logon?

Answer (score 1):

Create a DWORD under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList` named after your account, `cyg_server`, and set it to 0. This will hide the account from the login screen as well as from UAC.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/66400/hide-account-from-login-screen-but-can-be-used-in-uac